# DCom/OPC application does not connect when running in visual studio, but .exe connects perfectly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dcom, opc

I'm writing an OPC client that connects to a remote server and reads data etc.  I am using advosol's BGServer class.  The issue is, when I run the program in visual studio I get the following error on adding a group.

"Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040202"

My problem is similar to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978721/opc-server-access-remotely-using-opcda-net-tools), however, I know the DCom settings are configured correctly because when I run the same code by double clicking the .exe I connect and can add a group with no problems.

Therefore I'm guessing that visual studio is running under some strange user/group, and screws up the dcom permissions (mainly with callbacks).

edit: code

```
BGServer server;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server = new BGServer(this);
        server.Connect(new OPC.Common.Host() { HostName = "xp-devbox2", UserName = "OPCUser", Password = "OPCUser" }, "FactoryTalk Gateway", null, ServerConnected); 
    }
    void ServerConnected(BGException ex, object tag)
    {
        if (ex != null)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            //we've connected to the server.  let's start subscribing to stuff!
            server.AddGroup("Tuner DataGroup", true, 1000, 0, null, null, new OnBGSrvAddGroup(GroupAdded));
        }
    }
    private BGGroup dGroup;
    void GroupAdded(BGException ex, BGGroup group, object tag)
    {

        if (ex != null)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        else label1.Text = "Group Added";
    }
```

Comment: So the solution to this is kind of obvious.
In the debug portion of your project properties, uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".
This gets rid of vshost, and lets me connect.  
However, I have little to no idea what this does to debugging (and the msdn article on it is not so helpful), so use this carefully.

Comment: Also, I can't figure out how to turn off the hosting process in a wpf app... so there goes that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using reg-free COM to communicate with the OPC?  When you use the "Visual Studio Hosting Process" any external ".exe.manifest" files that you create the do reg-free COM will not be carried into the manifest of the vshost.exe process.